# how site versioning is configuration

Tags: 2013, versioning

Is it possible to configure versioning in a site to be automatically available in every document library created within the site?

If it is possible how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box this is not available. But you can do this

1. Using PowerShell enable versioning for all lists and libraries
2. Create a [list event receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver(v=office.14).aspx) and handle new list creation event
3. Create a manual process which users should follow. You can include this as part of governance plan.